# Cooking leftover sushi

Tags: food-safety, sushi

I have two day old tuna nigiri in the fridge which smells fine. What I've read says to eat it within 24 hours. But if I cook the tuna then I can just go with raw fish guidelines?

Comment: This is what I've always done with my left over sushi fish and I've never had a problem. As long as it smells fine, it should be fair game for cooking. Day old salmon sushi cooked is as good as any salmon I've ever bought for the purpose of cooking.